# WinCE - Unable to start debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, windows-ce, soti

Using a WinCE C# Forms app .NET3.5 on device [link](http://www.theonlinebasket.com/handheld-gps-navigator-and-mobile-phone-with-internet_p331.html)

I can deploy fine and run the forms application.

I can use the Windows CE Test Kit [link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=40b7cedb-dc8b-4503-8dc9-e75f8e8496c1) which automatically deploys itself to the device and it runs the tests.

**Problem:**  Debugging wont start.  It locks up VS2008.  It seems to deploy the app fine, then hangs.  Eventually comes up with "Unable to start debugging"

I cannot use SOTI [link](http://www.soti.net/PCPro/Default.aspx) as it fails to deploy itself to the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that CETK works is a red herring.  It uses a different transport (PlatMan) so whether or not is works actually has no bearing of whether a managed app will work (which uses CoreCon).

Studio debugging is very solid *provided* you have the right and same versions of CoreCon on the desktop and the device.  Have you upgraded to the latest service pack of Studio?  Does the target have CoreCon on it already?  Is the target version of CoreCon the same as what's on the development PC?  Do you have CF 3.5 only on the target, or is 2.0 also installed?  Is it the same SP version of the CF as you have on the PC?

Comment: Right - I'll need to dig into this.. appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

i already resolved this trouble by steps
1. Open MS Vs 2005->VS remote tool->remote registry editor
Highlight Windows CE 5.0 -> HKLM -> System
Right click in the right hand pane and select New DWORD value.
In the name field type (exactly and without the quotes) "CoreConOverrideSecurity" and set its value to 1 
Close the editor. Shut down the emulator with Save State.
refer: 
http://wincetips.blogspot.com/

Comment: The Studio Remote Tools use CoreCon to connect, so if you're unable to connect from Studio's debugger, you will also be unable to connect from the Remote Registry editor.  Essentially this is a catch-22.

Answer (score 0):

I were getting "unable to start" popup after the successful deployment in the emulator.  The CE Remote Process viewer tool could not show the trace of my program being added in the emulator. I have tried to attach the process of emulator to the VS2008 but it failed. Later I have reinstalled full installation of VS2008. It fixed the problem.