# Windows CE 7 - Unable to start debugging

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I'm Using a Windows CE C# Forms app .NET3.5 on Casio DT-X200-10E device.
And this runs **Windows CE 7**. My application is deploying successfully but it won't run on device by saying.

> Unable to start debugging

When I use my old device which has Windows CE 6 both deploying and debugging works fine.
I'm using Visual Studio 2008

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220830/wince-unable-to-start-debugging)?

Comment: is it first time you deploy your app or you try re-deploying?

Comment: @Martheen I've checked that. But couldn't understand the solution defined

Comment: @Badiparmagi I'm re-deploying and even in first time also it didn't work

Comment: Have you updated the SDK in your PC? Also, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474355/debugging-winmobile-application-on-remote-device-pda-arm-from-visual-studio) question. Deploying through cable only require regular MTP, while debugging will require CoreCon running with the appropriate version. In some device I found it's easier to just run CoreCon manually in the device, remote there, instead of using cables.

Comment: i deleted all exe and other files from my device and deployed then it worked.

Comment: @Badiparmagi still same

Comment: @tarzanbappa sorry to hear :(

Comment: @Martheen thanks, I'm already following those steps.. With my Win CE 6 devices debugging works, Win Ce 7 devices has the problem

Comment: did you try this [VS2008 update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11935)?

Comment: @salvolds When I try to install the update it says..` None of the products that are addressed by this software update are installed on this computer. Click Cancel to exit setup.`

Comment: I think I don't have VS 2008 SP1 I'll install it first and check.

Comment: @salvolds Still the problem exists

Comment: are you using ActiveSync for debugging?

Comment: hi, how did you solve your problem finally?